# 413: File entity too large ugly error

Tags: ajax, files

When uploading an image that exceeds the server PHP upload image, I get the following error:

[image]

My question is: Why is this error displayed so ugly and is there a way to display it more nicely, for example, in the form itself?

To be clear: I know why this error is thrown, it's just a matter of userfriendliness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are experiencing it on Chrome only it's a problem with your setup, not Drupal itself. Here you have [a bug report about it](https://drupal.org/node/951500).

But more probable is that it happens on all browsers, and it's a problem with nginx config - you need to set up `client_max_body_size` about 35% larger than max file size you want to allow people to upload using Drupal (to have safety margin for [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and alike). That way your Drupal will catch "to large" exceptions, and not your nginx.

Note - HTTP does not force body encoding, so 35% margin may well stay unused. But nothing stops applications from doing it, and 35% is what I experienced to be safest bet to avoid future surprises. Hardly any encoding or wrapping wastes as much as Base64 with it's 4/3 overhead. Better safe than sorry and if your server is willing to accept 20MB files, then 27MB will not kill it.